# Storyboard not rendering added views

Tags: ios7, storyboard, xcode6

I am trying to execute the steps described in iOS developer library [basics tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/FirstTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH3-SW1). When I add "Scene to story board" run the simulator, I am not seeing the label. It is just white screen. Not sure what is causing this issue. Any suggestions?

Environment:

iOS SDK7.1

XCode 6.0

Rented server machine from MacInCloud.

EDIT:
Here is snap shot of my Xcode:
[image: Here is snap shot of my Xcode:]

When I use "Single View Application" template, "Views" I am adding to story board are showing up properly in simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought to close this question first, but it seems not a good practice, so adding solution as answer.

I missed ***To configure the app delegate implementation file*** step from the documentation, which is why it is showing white screen. Make sure you delete the code which renders white background.

Answer (score 2):

It could be that the positioning of the label is outside of the visible screen. One quick way to rectify this would be to add a new Alignment Constraint so that the label is "Horizontal Center in Container". An example of how to add an Alignment Constraint below...

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Let me check.

Comment: No, it seems that didn't fix the issue. I have attached screenshot of my xcode.

Comment: Can you confirm you've correctly add the constraint(s), from the screenshot I can't seem to see it? You should see a list of them in the Document Outline (area containing "View Controller Scene", etc). Example here (note the "Constraints"): http://imgur.com/S3LvDB0